# Monotouch error crash log

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have an error in my release build app. Does anyone have an idea?

Incident Identifier: 9E3590C1-41C3-4E92-AB35-4E45551931B3
    CrashReporter Key:   a62caa0c7da6b2d1ddedda18b8354a223eb8d0b9
    Hardware Model:      iPad2,1
    Process:         PrintStand [8337]
    Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/669F0F9A-8464-489C-BCFB-A66343F011B7/MediawirePrintStandMobilePresentation.app/PrintStand
    Identifier:      PrintStand
    Version:         ??? (???)
    Code Type:       ARM (Native)
    Parent Process:  launchd [1]

```
Date/Time:       2012-07-03 17:50:40.890 +0300
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f4c32c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ddf208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33dd8298 abort + 88
3   PrintStand                      0x01276ec6 0x1000 + 19357382
4   PrintStand                      0x0128f9a2 0x1000 + 19458466
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33de97e6 _sigtramp + 42
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ddf208 pthread_kill + 48
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33dd8298 abort + 88
8   PrintStand                      0x01317eda 0x1000 + 20016858
9   PrintStand                      0x01317efc 0x1000 + 20016892
10  PrintStand                      0x012627ea 0x1000 + 19273706
11  PrintStand                      0x01276a54 0x1000 + 19356244
12  PrintStand                      0x01276b22 0x1000 + 19356450
13  PrintStand                      0x0128e6c6 0x1000 + 19453638
14  PrintStand                      0x00ff5f54 0x1000 + 16731988
15  PrintStand                      0x00ff5f54 0x1000 + 16731988
16  PrintStand                      0x011b6578 0x1000 + 18568568
17  PrintStand                      0x01264cd4 0x1000 + 19283156
18  PrintStand                      0x012dff58 0x1000 + 19787608
19  PrintStand                      0x0132d170 0x1000 + 20103536
20  CoreFoundation                  0x3152e3f6 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 46
21  UIKit                           0x3181ce00 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 56
22  UIKit                           0x3181cdbc -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 24
23  UIKit                           0x3181cd9a -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 38
24  UIKit                           0x3181cb0a -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 486
25  UIKit                           0x3181d442 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 470
26  UIKit                           0x3180fb80 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 5216
27  CoreFoundation                  0x315a8b14 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
28  CoreFoundation                  0x315a6d50 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 252
29  CoreFoundation                  0x315a70aa __CFRunLoopRun + 754
30  CoreFoundation                  0x3152a49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
31  CoreFoundation                  0x3152a366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
32  GraphicsServices                0x32a03432 GSEventRunModal + 130
33  UIKit                           0x3182fcce UIApplicationMain + 1074
34  PrintStand                      0x01020a1c 0x1000 + 16906780
35  PrintStand                      0x00bc30a0 0x1000 + 12329120
36  PrintStand                      0x011b6578 0x1000 + 18568568
37  PrintStand                      0x01264cd4 0x1000 + 19283156
38  PrintStand                      0x012dff58 0x1000 + 19787608
39  PrintStand                      0x012e2c38 0x1000 + 19799096
40  PrintStand                      0x012e6588 0x1000 + 19813768
41  PrintStand                      0x01269728 0x1000 + 19302184
42  PrintStand                      0x012618d6 0x1000 + 19269846
43  PrintStand                      0x00bb3104 0x1000 + 12263684

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f3c3a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3477af04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3477ac22 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f3c004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f3c1fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x315a83ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x315a7124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3152a49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3152a366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x31d4ac9c _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da072e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da05e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f4c628 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da4b1a nanosleep + 138
2   PrintStand                      0x0130cf60 0x1000 + 19971936
3   PrintStand                      0x012f38ba 0x1000 + 19867834
4   PrintStand                      0x012f9cee 0x1000 + 19893486
5   PrintStand                      0x0130da2a 0x1000 + 19974698
6   PrintStand                      0x01326a64 0x1000 + 20077156
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da072e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da05e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f3c06c semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   PrintStand                      0x01312ff6 0x1000 + 19996662
2   PrintStand                      0x012f5724 0x1000 + 19875620
3   PrintStand                      0x012f9cee 0x1000 + 19893486
4   PrintStand                      0x0130da2a 0x1000 + 19974698
5   PrintStand                      0x01326a64 0x1000 + 20077156
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da072e _pthread_start + 314
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da05e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f3c3a8 kevent + 24
1   PrintStand                      0x012f438a 0x1000 + 19870602
2   PrintStand                      0x012f9cee 0x1000 + 19893486
3   PrintStand                      0x0130da2a 0x1000 + 19974698
4   PrintStand                      0x01326a64 0x1000 + 20077156
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da072e _pthread_start + 314
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da05e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f3c06c semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   PrintStand                      0x01312ff6 0x1000 + 19996662
2   PrintStand                      0x012f5724 0x1000 + 19875620
3   PrintStand                      0x012f9cee 0x1000 + 19893486
4   PrintStand                      0x0130da2a 0x1000 + 19974698
5   PrintStand                      0x01326a64 0x1000 + 20077156
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da072e _pthread_start + 314
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da05e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f3c054 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   PrintStand                      0x01313054 0x1000 + 19996756
2   PrintStand                      0x012ada72 0x1000 + 19581554
3   PrintStand                      0x012f9cee 0x1000 + 19893486
4   PrintStand                      0x0130da2a 0x1000 + 19974698
5   PrintStand                      0x01326a64 0x1000 + 20077156
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da072e _pthread_start + 314
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33da05e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f4ccd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d9af36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d9acc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f4ccd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d9af36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d9acc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37f4ccd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d9af36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33d9acc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3ed7ed98      r6: 0x01412612      r7: 0x2fdfd38c
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x01412630     r11: 0x029da2a4
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfd380      lr: 0x33ddf20f      pc: 0x37f4c32c
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -  0x14e8fff +PrintStand armv7  <c1610e88f63f34988be9ffac81e9bdbb> /var/mobile/Applications/669F0F9A-8464-489C-BCFB-A66343F011B7/MediawirePrintStandMobilePresentation.app/PrintStand
 0x5906000 -  0x5916fff  Riven armv7  <46e4d9c7b88d3afca369efb40e3ff4d5> /System/Library/TextInput/Riven.bundle/Riven
0x2fedf000 - 0x2ff00fff  dyld armv7  <77eddfd654df393ba9c95ff01715fd08> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30372000 - 0x30381fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <a2363f8ed49932dba415d2d4cd32fb74> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x30382000 - 0x30384fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x30404000 - 0x30413fff  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x30414000 - 0x30414fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x30419000 - 0x30463fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x30561000 - 0x305a5fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x305a6000 - 0x305aefff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x305b9000 - 0x305bcfff  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x30629000 - 0x30642fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x30643000 - 0x30650fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x30c86000 - 0x30ca3fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x30d98000 - 0x30dddfff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x30dee000 - 0x30deefff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x30df2000 - 0x30e11fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x30e12000 - 0x30e28fff  EAP8021X armv7  <952fcfdec0633aff923768fca1a26fcb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x30ea1000 - 0x30f1afff  ProofReader armv7  <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x312e8000 - 0x31332fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f1fbb825def23043830a095b953a9c94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x31337000 - 0x31388fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x313c0000 - 0x313c5fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x313c6000 - 0x3140efff  CoreMedia armv7  <e274e1b894753b2eb05cf7b22a36d0c1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x31416000 - 0x314dcfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x3150b000 - 0x31514fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x3151b000 - 0x31632fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x31664000 - 0x31667fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x3169c000 - 0x317fbfff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <06a0a1ee488030169bdfab11fc8d2c5c> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x317fe000 - 0x31ca0fff  UIKit armv7  <cd513a2f22f53d698c3e10f6fe48a63e> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x31ca1000 - 0x32460fff  WebCore armv7  <2690c38c9c5f3c09975d619dd1dfbed7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x32473000 - 0x324a8fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x324df000 - 0x324dffff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x32574000 - 0x32577fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x3259f000 - 0x325edfff  CoreLocation armv7  <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x32711000 - 0x32715fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x327a7000 - 0x327a7fff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x327a8000 - 0x327befff  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x329ff000 - 0x32a09fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <cb64e146a8ee3fda9e80ffae1ccc9c5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x32b3f000 - 0x32b42fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x32c26000 - 0x32c69fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x32c6a000 - 0x32d8ffff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x32d90000 - 0x32d96fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x32e08000 - 0x32e48fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x32e49000 - 0x32e5dfff  PersistentConnection armv7  <54091a638f8731cd85ccf00fa06972c3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x32e83000 - 0x32ea7fff  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x32ec4000 - 0x32efcfff  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x33008000 - 0x331aefff  CoreData armv7  <b0215b6d4d143859a2b313ecade095ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x331af000 - 0x331b3fff  IOSurface armv7  <443ac3aab9283da480dd9dcda3c5c88e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x331d2000 - 0x331d2fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x331d5000 - 0x331dcfff  StoreKit armv7  <e00b0ead8b1030aaafe473eaeb04cafc> /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit
0x3334f000 - 0x33893fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x33b22000 - 0x33bccfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x33bcd000 - 0x33bd1fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x33bd2000 - 0x33ca2fff  WebKit armv7  <3c5dd2ec46fe3e189c25bba78ad88fa1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x33ca3000 - 0x33d91fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x33d92000 - 0x33e1efff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x33e2d000 - 0x33f76fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x340f2000 - 0x34237fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x3436e000 - 0x3437dfff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x34421000 - 0x34429fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x34478000 - 0x3449dfff  OpenCL armv7  <f4b08361179a3f6bb033415b0d7c6251> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x3449e000 - 0x3449ffff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x344ae000 - 0x3476ffff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34777000 - 0x3478dfff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x347d6000 - 0x347d7fff  CoreSurface armv7  <97f871f09f503c98a6371c2b657430d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x34817000 - 0x348c4fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3493a000 - 0x34a11fff  CFNetwork armv7  <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x34af7000 - 0x34afbfff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x34d92000 - 0x34e11fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x34e50000 - 0x34e99fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x34e9a000 - 0x34f72fff  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x35444000 - 0x35535fff  QuartzCore armv7  <35d64a9da5523ae08c9e41511fd3061b> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x3554e000 - 0x35552fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x35553000 - 0x355a4fff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x355a5000 - 0x355b1fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x355b2000 - 0x3560afff  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x3576f000 - 0x35775fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x35776000 - 0x35777fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x35957000 - 0x35959fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x35ae1000 - 0x35b51fff  CoreImage armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x35b97000 - 0x35b9cfff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x35bb0000 - 0x35be7fff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x35c41000 - 0x35c47fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x35c48000 - 0x35c6bfff  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x35f07000 - 0x35f0dfff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x35fe9000 - 0x35ff5fff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x36131000 - 0x36132fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x362e3000 - 0x364c7fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x364da000 - 0x36526fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <b8f80d5d594c31d2b5d8fba9fdedb7e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x365a9000 - 0x365aafff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x366d1000 - 0x366d1fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x366d2000 - 0x3670dfff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x36965000 - 0x3696ffff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x36b30000 - 0x36b3cfff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x36b91000 - 0x36ba2fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x36d96000 - 0x36d99fff  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x36e64000 - 0x36e7afff  DictionaryServices armv7  <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x36f2f000 - 0x36f33fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x36f34000 - 0x36f3bfff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x36f43000 - 0x36f7ffff  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x36f83000 - 0x36f98fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x36fb3000 - 0x36ff1fff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x36ff2000 - 0x37170fff  Foundation armv7  <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x371af000 - 0x371b6fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <38132ecfd74b325fb1a4142bab663c19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x371b7000 - 0x371d7fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x371d8000 - 0x371d9fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <6a8f2f33c7543808a0f4599101c3b61a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x373ba000 - 0x373bdfff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x373cb000 - 0x3773afff  TextInput armv7  <8d7f24642c7634cc8e3a6e65f1dcd98e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x3792a000 - 0x37930fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x37933000 - 0x3793efff  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x37ac0000 - 0x37ac0fff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x37cf1000 - 0x37d3afff  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x37d51000 - 0x37d5bfff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x37d7d000 - 0x37f3afff  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x37f3b000 - 0x37f51fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <311f379a9fde305d80c1b22b7dd2e52a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x37f5e000 - 0x37f5ffff  DataMigration armv7  <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x37f67000 - 0x37f78fff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. If you're using a binding project, does it support your ARM type? Here is a post with a similar error:

[MonoTouch Binding Library - EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303130/monotouch-binding-library-exc-bad-access-sigsegv)

Look at line 4 of this code:

https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/blob/master/Kiip/binding/libKiip.linkwith.cs

Try adding that to your link with file and see if it helps. You can also change your ARM by following these steps:

Right click your project
Go to iPhone Build > Advanced
Change the ARM drop down